# nginx supervisor django gunicorn 404

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I have been trying to deploy a django application through nginx following this tutorial: [karzynski](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/)

and here is my set up:

supervisor:

```
[program:eviotapro]
command = /home/effect/Desktop/workspace/Eviota/gunicorn_start.bash;             
user = root                                                          ; User to run as
stdout_logfile = /home/effect/Desktop/workspace/Eviota

/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log   ; Where to write log messages
redirect_stderr = true                                                ; Save stderr in the same log

environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 ; Set UTF-8 as default encoding
```

when I run the supervisor Everything seems ok and no problem is shown.

Here is my nginx configuration which I can't say I fully understand

```
upstream eviotapro_server {
  # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
  # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
  # single worker for timing out).

  server unix:/home/effect/Desktop/workspace/Eviota/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    listen   8005;
    server_name <ip address>;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /home/effect/Desktop/workspace/Eviota/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/effect/Desktop/workspace/Eviota/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias   /home/effect/Desktop/workspace/Eviota/eviotapro/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /home/effect/Desktop/workspace/Eviota/eviotapro/media/;
    }

    location / {
        # an HTTP header important enough to have its own Wikipedia entry:
        #   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # enable this if and only if you use HTTPS, this helps Rack
        # set the proper protocol for doing redirects:
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        # pass the Host: header from the client right along so redirects
        # can be set properly within the Rack application
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
        # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
        proxy_redirect off;

        # set "proxy_buffering off" *only* for Rainbows! when doing
        # Comet/long-poll stuff.  It's also safe to set if you're
        # using only serving fast clients with Unicorn + nginx.
        # Otherwise you _want_ nginx to buffer responses to slow
        # clients, really.
        # proxy_buffering off;

        # Try to serve static files from nginx, no point in making an
        # *application* server like Unicorn/Rainbows! serve static files.
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://<ip address>;
            break;
        }
    }

    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
       root /home/effect/Desktop/workspace/Eviota/eviotapro/static/;
    }
}
```

It simply shows nginx standart 404 and at its access log:

```
192.168.1.128 - - [16/Jul/2018:21:43:04 +0200] "GET /exact/generate/batch HTTP/1.1" 404 152 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"
```

and I can't seem to figure it out why, somewhere I configured something wrong I lost 3 days trying to find it, any help would be appreciated.

here is also my gunicorn bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="eviotapro_server"                                  # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/home/effect/Desktop/workspace/Eviota/eviotapro           # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/home/effect/Desktop/workspace/Eviota/run/gunicorn.sock  # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=root                                        # the user to run as
# GROUP=webapps                                     # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3                                     # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings             # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=eviotapro.wsgi                     # WSGI module name

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"


# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
export PATH="/home/effect/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
source activate eviotaenv
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER  \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
--log-file=-
```

output:

```
2018/07/16 17:49:21 [emerg] 6062#6062: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/07/16 17:49:21 [emerg] 6062#6062: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/07/16 17:49:21 [emerg] 6062#6062: bind() to 0.0.0.0:8005 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/07/16 17:49:21 [emerg] 6062#6062: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/07/16 17:49:21 [emerg] 6062#6062: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/07/16 17:49:21 [emerg] 6062#6062: bind() to 0.0.0.0:8005 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/07/16 17:49:21 [emerg] 6062#6062: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/07/16 17:49:21 [emerg] 6062#6062: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/07/16 17:49:21 [emerg] 6062#6062: bind() to 0.0.0.0:8005 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/07/16 17:49:21 [emerg] 6062#6062: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/07/16 17:49:21 [emerg] 6062#6062: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/07/16 17:49:21 [emerg] 6062#6062: bind() to 0.0.0.0:8005 failed (98: Address already in use)
2018/07/16 17:49:21 [emerg] 6062#6062: still could not bind()
2018/07/16 18:04:58 [emerg] 6885#6885: invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/eviotapro_server:54
2018/07/16 18:13:40 [emerg] 7398#7398: unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/eviotapro_server:19
```

output form netstat -tpln:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8005            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:63342         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6047/java       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4369            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6942          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6047/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::6378                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::5678                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::4369                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::15678                :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Comment: question: is that only nginx server block you have? including dummy ones you get with the installation. My point, are you sure `server_name` is correct? Do you curl? If yes do you do `localhost` or actual IP. Can you make sure you are hitting correct server block?

Comment: That is a good point, I didn't remove the default file in nginx directory because I wasn't aware that  there should be only one file there. (I don't understand I there shouldn't be but again I am new with nginx). Now everything gets directed to 500.html even the valid urls, any idea.

Comment: now I have this error on my logs:
*13 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Comment: There doesn't have to be, the point is are you hitting correct server block because if it does not match any `server_name` it will go for `default_server` or if that directive is not present for the 1st block available. Do `netstat -tlpn` check on what port is it listening. Also you mentioned removing, did you remove just the server block or something else as well? Can you please paste the output of the `tail -15 /var/log/nginx/error.log`.

Comment: I simply removed the default file in etc/nginx/sites-available, now there is only my custom file that I defined earlier. tail -15 /var/log/nginx/error.log seems to reveal something but still got me confused. the netstat -tlpn reveals that it should be listening to port 8005 as defined. updated the response.

Comment: Do you have apache on you PC? Try sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop

Comment: just tried, command not found, also I don't remember installing apache

Comment: Ok so Ubuntu I suppose, if not sensitive trow one line of that error.log here for inspection. Remove `server_name <ip address>;` this line and update this `listen   8005 default_server;` for testing purposes, try curling again, if failing and server is remote curl `localhost` from the remote server. @Erindy

Comment: 'sudo fuser -k 80/tcp'   followed by 'sudo service nginx start'

Comment: I removed <ip address> and I updated as you said, restarted nginx service and I still get the the 502 error, bad getway from the log files. Then I did as you suggested adding localhost and still same result.

Comment: @Bayko tried as you said, no luck, still the same. I am pretty sure I am missing something obvious

Comment: can it be because I have the sock file in unix:/home/effect/Desktop/workspace/Eviota/run/gunicorn.sock and it is running with root. although I don't see any problem there.

Comment: nginx 5xx error pages normally indicate their is a problem with your nginx config, try using the example config from the gunicorn docs http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html. Check that gunicorn is reachable on your socket with "curl --unix-socket /gunicorn/socket/path http", if that fails your socket may be getting killed. Finally with a good gunicorn and nginx it could be your actual application giving you errors so try running the django server and see if it has any issues.